# MySQL 8 nested select with count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-8.0

```
SELECT mapname, 
    (SELECT count(1)+1 FROM ck_bonus b WHERE a.mapname=b.mapname AND a.runtime > b.runtime AND a.zonegroup = b.zonegroup AND b.style = %i) AS rank, 
    (SELECT count(1) FROM ck_bonus b WHERE a.mapname = b.mapname AND a.zonegroup = b.zonegroup AND b.style = %i) as total 
    FROM ck_bonus a WHERE steamid = '%s' AND style = %i;
```

This bit of code used to work perfectly fine pre MySQL8 update, but now spits with this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
 'rank, (SELECT count(1) FROM ck_bonus b WHERE a.mapname = b.mapname AND a.zonegro' at line 1
```

I  went through google and I couldn't find the right answer.
replacing count(1) with count() or count (*) didn't help.

What should this query look like for MySQL8?

Comment: Rank becomes a reserved word in 8.0.2 try a different alias, and you might want to rewrite this query to take advantage of the window functions in 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word `rank` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R) in MySql 8.

So use another alias name, or backtick the alias name.

And in MySql 8 you can use [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)

```
SELECT 
 mapname, 
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY mapname, zonegroup, steamid, style ORDER BY runtime DESC) AS `rank`,
 COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY mapname, zonegroup, steamid, style) AS total
FROM ck_bonus 
WHERE steamid = '%s' AND style = %i;
```

Comment: @olokos. Thx for the rep.  Btw, if you're going to simplify it using window functions. Note that I used DENSE_RANK, but depending on what the results should be, then it could require a ROW_NUMBER instead. So you'd have to test which window function you really need. And if the PARTITION is correct.

Comment: I decided to keep it simple and just use backticks, for simplicity sake :p

Comment: @olokos Probably for the best. :-)  It might give different numbers anyway, because those nested queries in the original SQL don't consider a same "steamid" in the counts.  But window functions are processed after the WHERE & HAVING, so they could return less since the WHERE has a criteria on "steamid".

Comment: It might give different numbers, in which case? It should be all good when using backticks, right?

Comment: I ment a diference betwéen using the window functions compared to using nested queries.

Answer (score 0):

You missed single quotes in `outer` & `subquery` :

```
SELECT mapname, 
       (SELECT count(1) FROM ck_bonus b WHERE a.mapname = b.mapname AND a.runtime > b.runtime AND a.zonegroup = b.zonegroup AND b.style = '%i') + 1 AS rnk, 
       (SELECT count(1) FROM ck_bonus b WHERE a.mapname = b.mapname AND a.zonegroup = b.zonegroup AND b.style = '%i') as total 
FROM ck_bonus a 
WHERE steamid = '%s' AND style = '%i';
```

I suspect you need `LIKE` predicate instead of `=`.