# Query SELECT COALESCE(SELECT, ...) not working with MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql

With MySQL 5 this query worked without any issue:

```
SELECT 1+COUNT(*) AS rank 
FROM userpoints 
WHERE points > COALESCE((SELECT points FROM userpoints WHERE userid=(SELECT userid FROM users WHERE handle='abc123' LIMIT 1)), 0)
```

With MySQL 8.0.23 it throws an error:

> MySQL query error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Is it not allowed to "embed" SELECTs into other SELECTs anymore? See the `userid=(SELECT...` part.

Or is it a problem with `COALESCE`?

Comment: I found it, I think! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343203/mysql-8-nested-select-with-count - "The word rank is a reserved word in MySql 8."

Comment: Always provide **complete** error message. You have truncated the most critical part of it...